# NullReferenceException after displaying a table on DataGridView more than once

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

Edit 2: Turns out it only gives a `NullReferenceException` the first time. After that, it says that I am not allowed to change the `ConnectionString` property, even though I think I have closed it in the right places.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I am working on a WinForms application that uses an MS Access database, and I am currently having problems with an entry deletion feature I made.

So, I have a `DataGridView` that switches between 3 tables on a button click, and I have a function that deletes a row on a table that is currently open by clicking a button that is at the end of the row.

When I open my first table, and try to delete a row, it works just fine. However, if I open a different table afterwards and try to delete an entry, or even go back to the first table I opened, I get a `NullReferenceException` in the deletion function.

Here is the code to display one of the tables in `DataGridView`.

```
public DataTable Read()
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        OpenConnection(); //connection.Open() inside an if statement
        dataTable.Clear();
        OleDbCommand readStudentCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from Students", connection); //display the whole list of students

        OleDbDataReader reader = readStudentCommand.ExecuteReader();
        dataTable.Load(reader);
        connection.Close();
        return dataTable;        
    }
```

Here is the code that deletes an entry

```
    private void MainDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        if (ConnectionState.Closed == connection.State)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == MainDataGridView.Columns["Delete"])
        {
//this function retrieves the first column value of the deleted row, which has the ID of the entry (works with any table). 
    DeleteEntry(MainDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()); //exception thrown here (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null)
        MainDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
     }
```

and here is `DeleteEntry()`

```
private void DeleteEntry(string deletedID)
    {
        string tableName = null;
        string idType = null;
        if (studentsDisplayed)
        {
            tableName = "Students";
            idType = "Student ID";
        }
        else if(booksDisplayed)
        {
            tableName = "Books";
            idType = "BookID";
        }
        else if(loansDisplayed)
        {
            tableName = "Loans";
            idType = "Loan ID";
        }
        string deleteCommand = String.Format("DELETE * FROM {0} WHERE [{1}] = {2}", tableName, idType, deletedID);
        OleDbCommand deleteEntryCommand = new OleDbCommand(deleteCommand, connection);
        deleteEntryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SaveData(); //this method just calls Update() in a dataAdapter of a relevant table
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Thank you!

Edit:
As per request, here is the code that switches the table. It simply references the first function and sets the returned `dataTable` as `DataSource`.

```
private void StudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //display students
    {
        try
        {
            if (!studentsDisplayed)
            {
                MainDataGridView.DataSource = studentDAL.Read(); //studentDAL is the class that works with the Students table of my DB.
                studentsDisplayed = true; //these 3 are to avoid duplicated creation of the same table
                booksDisplayed = false;
                loansDisplayed = false;
                ComboBoxChanger(); //don't mind this, it's for an irrelevant feature
                CreateButtons(5);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line line exactly you have the exception?

Comment: I mentioned it in the comments, but right here: 
  
 DeleteEntry(MainDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

Comment: Ah sorry about that, is it possible to add the code which does the table switch?

Comment: Added. Note that there are 2 more functions like this that are the almost the same but for opening the other 2 tables I have. It's true that my code is a bit inefficient, but I must fix it first before polishing IMO.

Comment: Try to add _dataTable.Columns.Clear();_  after _dataTable.Clear();_

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work, and caused more problems. However, I think I am onto something. Sometimes (no changes introduced to the code), instead of a `NullReferenceException`, I get a `ConnectionString` error, saying that I am not allowed to change it and it is already open. Let me see what that could be caused by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so turns out the problem was the fact that `DeleteEntry(MainDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString())` had a problem with the `Cells[0]` part. After the first time loading a table, the 0th cell just vanished. So, I rewrote the code so that instead of declaring `tableName` and `idType` in `DeleteEntry()`, they're declared in `MainDataGridView_CellContentClick()`, and then made the `DeleteEntry()` accept 3 `idType` and `tableName` as parameters, and changed the `MainDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` argument to `MainDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[idType].Value.ToString()`. Now it works just fine!